# Inside a loop a linked list seems to be ok but outside it is empty

Tags: c, pointers, struct, while-loop, malloc

I just started learning C, and I'm lost trying to read cars and their manufacturing years from a text file. The program says it doesn't find any cars when I try it with a .txt file containing the following rows:

```
Lada 1976
Ferrari 2005
Suzuki 1985
Volvo 1963
Toyota 1993
Honda 2011
```

I did a similar linked list program which read an integer from a user to be added to the list, instead of a file. I think this is completely identical, except now the program reads from a file. This goes wrong somewhere with the pointer `first` (my best guess from debugging prints I added to several places) or it could be that I have somehow managed to change the nodes only inside the while loop (another guess). Could someone point out what is wrong here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct car {
    char brand[15];
    int year; 
    struct car *prev; 
    struct car *next; 
} car;

void readCars(char *fname, car *newCar, car *first, car *last);
void printCars(car *ptr, car *first);
void freeMemory(car *ptr, car *first);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    car *first = NULL; // a pointer to the first node of the linked list
    car *last = NULL; // a pointer to the last node of the linked list
    car *newCar; // a pointer for new nodes
    car *ptr; // a pointer for iterating the linked list
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("No filename provided.\n");
        exit(0);
    } 
    printf("Reading the file %s.\n", argv[1]);
    readCars(argv[1], newCar, first, last);
    printCars(ptr, first);
    freeMemory(ptr, first);
    printf("Program ended.\n");
    return(0);
}

void readCars(char *fname, car *newCar, car *first, car *last) {    
    FILE *tiedosto;
    char rivi[22];
    if ((tiedosto = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\nProgram ended.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while (fgets(rivi, 22, tiedosto) != NULL) {
        if ((newCar = (car*)malloc(sizeof(car))) == NULL) { // allocate memory for a new node
                perror("Memory allocation failure.\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        sscanf(rivi, "%s %d", newCar->brand, &newCar->year); // set the car brand and age to the new node
        newCar->next = NULL; // set the pointer to next node to NULL as there is no next node
        newCar->prev = last; // set the pointer to the previous node to the previous last node (NULL if there was no previous)
        if (first == NULL) { 
            first = newCar; // the new node is the only node so it is the first node
            last = newCar; // the new node is the only node so it is also the last node
        } else {
            last->next = newCar; // the new node is next node of the previous last node
            last = newCar; // the new node is now the last node
        }
    }
    fclose(tiedosto);
    printf("File read into a linked list.\n");
}

void printCars(car *ptr, car *first) {
    if(first == NULL) {
        printf("No cars found.\n");
    } else {
        ptr = first;
        int count = 1;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            printf("%d. car: %s from the year %d.\n", count, ptr->brand, ptr->year);
            count += 1;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}

void freeMemory(car *ptr, car *first) { 
    ptr = first;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        first = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = first;
    }
    printf("Memory freed.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
if (first == NULL) { 
    first = newCar; // the new node is the only node so it is the first node
    last = newCar; // the new node is the only node so it is also the last node
} else {
    last->next = newCar; // the new node is next node of the previous last node
    last = newCar; // the new node is now the last node
}
```

in the function `readCars` only modify the variables `first` and `last` in the function `readCars`. They do not modify the variables `first` and `last` in the function `main`.

Therefore, the variable `first` in the function `main` will stay `NULL`, so, as far as that function is concerned, the linked list stays empty.

In order to solve the problem, the function `main` should not pass copies of the variables `first` and `last` to the function `readCars`, but should rather pass pointers (i.e. references) to these variables. So you should change the parameters of the function `readCars` to the following:

```
void readCars(char *fname, car *newCar, car **first, car **last)
```

You should also change the lines quoted above to the following:

```
if ( *first == NULL ) { 
    *first = newCar; // the new node is the only node so it is the first node
    *last = newCar; // the new node is the only node so it is also the last node
} else {
    (*last)->next = newCar; // the new node is next node of the previous last node
    (*last) = newCar; // the new node is now the last node
}
```

Also, the parameter `newCar` of the function `readCars` does not serve any purpose as a parameter. You are instead using it as a local variable, so you should declare it as such and remove it from the parameter list of the function.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comment below, you are doing the same thing with the parameter `ptr` in the functions `printCars` and `freeMemory`. You should remove that parameter from these functions too.

Comment: Argh, Andreas, you beat me to it. @Jonne, To further add to what Andreas said, you seem to use parameters in place of local variables (you did that with `car = newCar` and `ptr = ptr` which is a very strange way of coding. This is related to the last sentence Andreas said. Normally local variables should serve locally or at most if they are relevant to anything called later on. You don't use then just to not declare them later, if you won't return or have them as an out parameter. Also, start using `nullptr` instead of NULL and get used to setting freed pointers to nullptr (or NULL at least).

Comment: @TheNomad: Most compilers do not support `nullptr` yet, at least on default settings. For example, the compilers gcc and clang only support it with the `std=c2x` or `std=gnu2x` command-line options.

Comment: GCC supports C++17 since a long time. It just might need std::nullptr instead of nullptr. And yes, it does need the flag for the standard, but it's normal. MSVC has the same thing. You select the standard you want to compile in.

Comment: Aha, a pointer to a pointer. I got his now, thank you very much. But there's a problem. The corrected program prints an extra line to the end of the proper car list: `7. car:  from the year 0`. How to stop that from happening?

Comment: @TheNomad: Please note that this question is tagged C, not C++. It is only in C23 that `nullptr` will be introduced to C. So it officially does not exist yet in C. In C++, it has existed for much longer, at least since C++11.

Comment: @Jonne: Do you maybe have a non-empty line at the end of your file. This could cause `fgets` to succeed on that line (i.e. to return non-`NULL`), but `sscanf` to fail. I suggest that you check the return value of `sscanf`, for example like this: `if ( sscanf(rivi, "%s %d", newCar->brand, &newCar->year ) != 2 ) { free( newCar ); continue; }`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your suggestion and think about the corrected code to increase my understanding.

Comment: @Andreeas: correct. I was under the impression it was already in C-17. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct car {
    char brand[15];
    int year; 
    struct car *prev; 
    struct car *next; 
} car;

void readCars(char *fname, car *newCar, car **first, car **last);
void printCars(car *ptr, car *first);
void freeMemory(car *ptr, car *first);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    car *first = NULL; // a pointer to the first node of the linked list
    car *last = NULL; // a pointer to the last node of the linked list
    car *newCar; // a pointer for new nodes
    car *ptr; // a pointer for iterating the linked list
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("No filename provided.\n");
        exit(0);
    } 
    printf("Reading the file %s.\n", argv[1]);
    readCars(argv[1], newCar, &first, &last);
    printCars(ptr, first);
    freeMemory(ptr, first);
    printf("Program ended.\n");
    return(0);
}

void readCars(char *fname, car *newCar, car **first, car **last) {    
    FILE *tiedosto;
    char rivi[22];
    if ((tiedosto = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\nProgram ended.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while (fgets(rivi, 22, tiedosto) != NULL) {
        if ((newCar = (car*)malloc(sizeof(car))) == NULL) { // allocate memory for a new node
                perror("Memory allocation failure.\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        sscanf(rivi, "%s %d", newCar->brand, &newCar->year); // set the  car brand and age to the new node
        newCar->next = NULL; // set the pointer to next node to NULL as  there is no next node
        newCar->prev = *last; // set the pointer to the previous node to  the previous last node (NULL if there was no previous)
        if (*first == NULL) {
            *first = newCar; // the new node is the only node so it is the  first node
            *last = newCar; // the new node is the only node so it is also  the last node
        } else {
            (*last)->next = newCar; // the new node is next node of the previous last node
            *last = newCar; // the new node is now the last node
        }
    }
    fclose(tiedosto);
    printf("File read into a linked list.\n");
}

void printCars(car *ptr, car *first) {
    if(first == NULL) {
        printf("No cars found.\n");
    } else {
        ptr = first;
        int count = 1;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            printf("%d. car: %s from the year %d.\n", count, ptr->brand,  ptr->year);
            count += 1;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}

void freeMemory(car *ptr, car *first) { 
    ptr = first;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        first = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = first;
    }
    printf("Memory freed.\n");
}
```

The main difference is that readCars needs a pointer to pointer to first and last. In this way, when the functions ends, the value of first and last does not change to the initial value (in the case NULL).
Let me know if you've understood.

Comment: Yes, this is clear now. The corrected program prints an extra line to the end of the proper car list: `7. car:  from the year 0`. How to stop that from happening?

Comment: do you have a free line at the end of the input file?
What you can do is you can check if the input parameters are not empty.